# this.$destroy vs v-if vue js with pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, destroy

i have a menu with many items. on item click I create a new Vue element (with Vuex store). The question is:

on close witch is outside the vue instance do I have to call this.$destroy or v-if="false" the root element.

```
<template> 
   <div v-if="closeVar">
     ....
   </div> 
</template>
<script>
 export default {
   ...,
   data() {
      return {
          closeVar: true
      };
   },
   methods: {
      onWindowsClose() {
          this.$destroy() OR this.closeVar = false; ????
      }
   },
   created() {
       window[id + 'onWindowsClose'] = this.onWindowsClose;
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`$destroy`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy) docs:

> In normal use cases you shouldn’t have to call this method yourself. Prefer controlling the lifecycle of child components in a data-driven fashion using `v-if` and `v-for`.

So the answer from the docs is that it's preferred to use `v-if`.  Furthermore, you should place that `v-if` on the component's tag in the parent, not within the component on the root element:

*Parent*

```
<child v-if="closeVar"></child>
```

Otherwise, you'd only be removing the child's content rather than the entire component.

The difference there is, for example, the child's `created` hook would not be called again if you repopulated that particular instance with content (which would be possible because the component wouldn't have been destroyed.)

Comment: this is not a component, it is the root element (new Vue{..., store}).$mount('.app'). if i use the v-if way the store will be destroyed?

Comment: It's in a .vue file so it's clearly a component, even if the root component. Maybe you are really asking a different question: "How to destroy a Vue app instance",  which is different from destroying the root component.  None of the code shown would be relevant to that question